# Algorithm for string replacement based on conditional char replacement

Tags: string, lisp, scheme, dsl

Usage case: I'm writing a domain specific language (DSL) for a regex-like but way more powerful Lispy string processing system focused on conditional replacements (like simulation of language evolution for conlangers/linguists) rather than matching as regexes do. As usual I wrote down the specs before actually writing down the code.

However, due to a somewhat stupid but hard to fix mistake, I ended up with a system only capable of doing stuff one char at a time. Thus, a rewrite rule might be (in pseudocode) `change 'a' to 'e' when last char is 's' and next char is 'd'`. Chars can also be deleted: `delete 'a' when ...`.

Since the interpreter for the DSL is a bit spaghetti-ish (not in the sense of unstructured, but in the sense that 1. I haven't figured out OO for my implementation lang Chicken Scheme 2. No IDE, so must remember 20+ variable names and use emacs) I don't want to touch it, but rather "unsugar" string replacements to conditional char replacements.

The trivial example: `change "ab" to "cd" unconditionally` rewrites to `change 'a' to 'c' when followed by 'b'; change 'b' to 'd' when preceded by a`. However, when there are conditions, things become very ugly very quick. Is there some easy recursive way to do the rewriting, or is this nearly impossible in the rewriting phase and I should probably fix my DSL interpreter? (Note: my DSL has ways to get the n-th letter before and after the current char)

Comment: If you turn _change 'ab' to 'cd' unconditionally_ into _change 'a' to 'c' when followed by 'b'; change 'b' to 'd' when preceded by 'a'_, you also need to do these in parallel, right?  If you _change 'a' to c' when followed by 'b'_ first, you turn 'ab' into 'cb', and then _change 'b' to 'd' when preceded by 'a'_ no longer applies, because 'b' is no longer preceded by 'a'.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, my DSL does everything in parallel. There are different syntax for parallel and sequential application of rules ;)

Comment: If it does everything in parallel, then how does the rule that you described function correctly?  Sorry if I'm missing something…

Comment: All rules are applied based on the environment of the char in the *original* text, not in whatever text produced by the previous rules. This ensures that something like `replace anything following 'e' by 'e'` doesn't trash the entire string etc.

Comment: Essentially, it is a purely functional zipper that is zipped along, with a string outputted into an accumulator. The zippers are obviously immutable and each character is passed through the DSL-interpreting function with the forward and backward zippers (remaining and previous chars). Thus, any previous changes are "thrown" into the output accumulator and thus essentially are "parallel".

Comment: If you make two changes in parallel, but a single overall result is expected, the changes have to be merged.  There could be conflicts: alter-alter conflicts, alter-delete conflicts. To merge, you have to know what has been altered where and how in all of the parallel versions relative to the original.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since we are going through the data character-at-a-time, when a condition is applied to a multi-character string, that condition has to be expressed in different ways for every position. For instance `"abc" followed by "x"` combines in a straightforward way into the condition for `a`, `b` and `c`, but has to change shape. The `x` is actually three positions away from `a`, but only two from `b`. This is bad because it causes a proliferation of conditions, which all get wastefully evaluated.

I'd solve this by adding the concept of frames into the interpreter. A frame is established at the current character position, and then holds that position somehow, allowing frame-relative addressing of the characters.

I can think of a few ways of introducing this position fixing. One would be to introduce variable binding into the interpreter. It could support a pair of instructions **bind *symbol*** and **unbind *n***, where we would be using a *gensym* for the symbol.

When generating the code for an operation on a string like `"abc"`, we would generate an instruction like `bind #:g0025`, which would fix the position of the `a`, and then the compiler will analyze the conditions applied to the string, and re-phrase them in terms that are relative to `#:g0025`. After the processing of `"abc"`, we would emit `unbind 1` to drop the most recently bound variable.

We could also bind variables to the Boolean values of conditions.

As an example with the named frames, suppose we have

```
Replace "abc" with "ijk" when preceded by "x" and followed by "yz".
```

This goes to something like:

```
bind #:frame
bind #:cond0 to when #:frame[-1] is "x" and #:frame[3] is "y" and #:frame[4] is "z"
replace "a" with "i" when #:cond0  ; these insns move the char position
replace "b" with "j" when #:cond0 
replace "c" with "k" when #:cond0
unbind 2
```

So the difficulty has been translated to one of compiling the condition into frame-relative addressing. The #:frame[3] is derived from the length of the `"abc"` pattern, which is available to the translator all at once. That is information not available in the target language, which doesn't have `"abc"` all at once.

The system almost certainly needs some way to try different matches at the same location. If there is no `"abc"` at the current position, another rule which replaces `"foo"` with something has to be tried at the same position. Perhaps when the conditions fail, the instruction doesn't advance the character position. So in our example above, that would work: all instructions share the same condition, so in the case of a match the position moves by three positions, otherwise it doesn't. Still, in spite of that, there may be a requirement to have multiple edits with different conditions at the same spot. The scope of my answer isn't to design the whole thing, though.